# Read row in a file and print out portion of string

Tags: c

Hi I have a text file from whitch i read row by row and paste result into a new file only a portion of string contained between character ! and character $

example:
origin:

```
Beautifull!day today$
!hello world$is nice
```

final:

```
day today
hello world
```

I have used in past this code and it was working now the output is an empty file.

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <alloc.h>
#include <string.h>



FILE *string;
FILE *stringtxt;
int line = 0;
int i = 0;
int j;
char search = 33;
char search2 = 36;



int main(void) 
{   

stringtxt = fopen("C:\\Users\\Pc\\Desktop\\ups.m3u","a+");

if ((string = fopen("C:\\Users\\Pc\\Desktop\\ups.txt","a+")) == 0)
        printf ("ERRORE");

    else{   
    char input[512];

        while (fgets(input,512,string)){
line++;
i = strlen(input);

            for(j=0;j<i;j++){
            if(input[j]==search){
            input[j-0] = 0;
                
                }
            }
            

            
            for(j=0;j<i;j++){
                if(input[j]==search2){
                
            memmove(input,input + j + 1, strlen(input));
            
            printf("%s\n",input);

fprintf(stringtxt,"%s\n",input);
                
                }
            }   
}       
}   


    fclose(stringtxt);

}
```

Comment: Is that some obfuscating task? Why do you call a `FILE` pointer `string`?

Comment: Also indent your code properly.

Comment: Please apply some decent formatting to your code. Readability and especially indentation is important to understand code. Naming that is more descriptive than confusing would also be appreciated. Using magic numbers like `33` instead of `'!'` also adds confusion and should be avoided.

Comment: If you're reading from handle `string`, then shouldn't that handle be opened with `r` instead of `a+`?

Comment: What is your output when you run that program with the shown input file?

Comment: When I execute the code on your sample I do get an empty output file but only if I use your `a+` mode for the input. If I use `r` mode, then I get output.

Comment: Your program also prints to `stdout` I assume this output is also missing. Why do you want to open an input file in append mode?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the description of `"a+"` in the [manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) Especially the part about initial reading position is important for your problem.

Comment: When you open a file with `a+`, the handle's position is set to EOF. If you either open with `r` or fseek to the beginning of the input file, then life will be better.

Comment: You refered the input being
```Beautifull!day today$ !hello world$is nice```
but shouldn't it be 
```Beautifull!day today! $hello world$is nice``````Beautifull!day today$ !hello world$is nice```
Unless you refer using both ! or $ as delimiter's could you clarify it?

Comment: Jeff Holt could you rewrite me the code that worked for you with an example

Comment: What output do you want for lines like `foo!bar!baz$qux$` or `foo!bar` or `foo$bar`?  The problem does not seem well specified.

Comment: foo!bar$!baz$qux the output will be barbaz

Comment: @Miroslav that is not the input mentioned by William Pursell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have various little errors in your code which prevent your program to do what you want.

As you read from one file and write to the other **from the beginning** you should use `"r"` mode to read and `"w"` mode to write. That would fix the problem that `"a"` sets the file pointer at the end of file and only allow it to grow.

Then if you want to extract the part starting at `search` and ending at `search2` you should swap the variables.

With those minimal fixes it will become:

```
...
stringtxt = fopen("C:\\Users\\Pc\\Desktop\\ups.m3u","w");       // change 1

if ((string = fopen("C:\\Users\\Pc\\Desktop\\ups.txt","r")) == 0)  //change 2
        printf ("ERRORE");
else{   
    char input[512];

    while (fgets(input,512,string)){
        line++;
        i = strlen(input);

        for(j=0;j<i;j++){
            if(input[j]==search2){            // change 3
                input[j-0] = 0;
            }
        }
        for(j=0;j<i;j++){
            if(input[j]==search){        // change 4
                memmove(input,input + j + 1, strlen(input));
                printf("%s\n",input);
                fprintf(stringtxt,"%s\n",input);
            }
            ...
```

Above code also cleaned indentation and produces the expected result.

Comment: Yes it work now, now i examine better the code but it work like

Answer (score 0):

From your response to my comment, it seems like you would be satisfied with:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void)
{
        int c;
        int p = 0;
        while( ( c = getchar()) != EOF ) {
                switch(c){
                case '\n': putchar(c); /* fallthru */
                case '$': p=0;
                }
                if( p ){
                        putchar(c);
                }
                if( c == '!' ){
                        p = 1;
                }
        }
}
```

With problems like this, it is often not necessary to actually read full lines, and it is much simpler if you do not.  This solution will print the data between the first `!` and the first `$`.  If you want to match on the inner pair, or the outer pair, it becomes necessary to read more than one character.